Elixir not finding erlang library
I'm getting back at an old phoenix project I stopped working on 3 years ago. While trying to compile it, I keep having an error I couldn't resolve for the whole afternoon.
== Compilation error in file lib/mppm/game_server/server_config.ex ==
** (ArgumentError) lib file xmerl-2.0/include/xmerl.hrl could not be found
    (elixir 1.17.2) lib/record/extractor.ex:41: Record.Extractor.from_lib_file/1
    (elixir 1.17.2) lib/record/extractor.ex:18: Record.Extractor.from_or_from_lib_file/1
    (elixir 1.17.2) lib/record/extractor.ex:5: Record.Extractor.extract/2
    lib/mppm/game_server/server_config.ex:9: (module)

With the culprit line being:
      defrecord(:xmlElement, extract(:xmlElement, from_lib: "xmerl/include/xmerl.hrl"))

I installed both Elixir (1.17) and Erlang/OTP (27.0.1) with asdf. I've checked the path where erlang libraries are (.asdf/installs/erlang/27.0.1/lib/). "xmerl" appears as "xmerl-2.0" so I tried correcting it, no luck. I tried absolute path and quite everything, including naively removing the from_lib argument, still no luck.
What am I missing here? I'm sure it's dumb, but I've been stuck for hours...
Thank you!

Since v1.15, elixir compiler prunes code pathes if it does not see them needed. erlang core suffers from that.
Add the following line into project/0 callback of your mix.exs.
def project do
  [
    …
    prune_code_paths: Mix.env() == :prod,
    …
  ]


I think the better option would be to use :extra_application in mix.exs.
